# Zend framework 2 radio buttons

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework2

Is there a way to put image in the radio button. Like the following example.

http://jsbin.com/awelaw/1/edit

I am trying to achieve this using Zend forms. So far i havent been able to achieve this. Below is my code:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
        'name'  => 'radio',

        'attributes' => array(
            'class'=>'pay',
         ),

        'options' => array(
            'value_options' => array(
                'Visa' => array(
                'value' => 'Visa',
                'attributes' => array(
                   'id'=>'visa',
                   'class'=>'pay',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'img'   => 'src="../img/visa_debit.gif"',
                            ),
                    ),

             ),
        ),
    ));
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually render the checkbox if you need custom HTML. See [this part of the official Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#rendering) for more information.